# How do modern OS's achieve idempotent cleanup functions for process deaths?

Tags: memory, process, operating-system, resource-cleanup

Let's say that I have an OS that implements malloc by storing a list of segments that the process points to in a process control block. I grab my memory from a free list and give it to the process.

If that process dies, I simply remove the reference to the segment from the process control block, and move the segment back to my free list.

Is it possible to create an idempotent function that does this process cleanup? How is it possible to create a function such that it can be called again, regardless of whether it was called many times before or if previous calls died in the middle of executing the cleanup function? It seems to me that you can't execute two move commands atomically.

How do modern OS's implement the magic involved in culling memory from processes that randomly die? How do they implement it so that it's okay for even the process performing the cull to randomly die, or is this a false assumption that I made?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your question boils down to how the OS culls a process's memory if that process crashes.

Although I'm self educated in these matters, I'll give you two ways an OS can make sure any memory used by a process is reclaimed if the process crashes.

**In a typical modern CPU and modern OS with virtual memory:**

You have two layers of allocation. Whenever the process calls malloc, malloc tries to satisfy the request from already available memory pages the kernel gave the process. If not enough pages are available, malloc asks the kernel to allocate more pages.
In this case, whenever a process crashes or even if it exits normally, the kernel doesn't care what malloc did, or what memory the process forgot to release. It only needs to free all the pages it gave the process.

**In a simpler OS that doesn't care much about performance, memory fragmentation or virtual memory and maybe not even about memory protection:**

Malloc/free is implemented completely on the kernel side (e.g: system calls). Whenever a process calls malloc/free, the kernel does all the work, and therefore knows about all the memory that needs to be freed. Once the process crashes or exits, the kernel can cleanup. Since the kernel is never supposed to crash, and keep a record of all the allocated memory per process, it's trivial.

Like I said, I'm self educated, and I didn't check how for example Linux or Windows implement it.

Comment: So is the cleanup function idempotent but not crash-safe? Whoever's calling it (the kernel) is never supposed to crash. If it did, you get a blue screen basically. I think that sounds right, but it also seems sort of unsafe to have the core kernel manage memory for all processes going on.

Comment: @JonathanPark it has to - nothing else can at the level of the entire process. That' why RuiFig explaned that most non-trivial OS manage whole pages allocated, and each process often runs a heap sub-allocator accessed via internal malloc/free type library calls.  As long as page limits and permissions are not violated, the OS does not know or care about any language/library specific sub-allocator.  If a process elects to die, or the OS needs to kill it, the OS can simply, (!), remove execution from all its threads, deallocate all non-shared pages and other resources and the process is >gone<

Comment: What @MartinJames said.
The Kernel initially gives X whole pages to the process to play with, and more whole pages as required if the process needs more memory.
The process then uses whatever algorithm it wants to split those pages into individual chunks (the calls to malloc)
That's why the kernel doesn't even care if a process calls free or not.
Once the process crashes or exits, it just reclaims all the pages it gave the process.